# Rewriting LINQ to SQL class using DataContext

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have written a function to insert some data into SQL table based on the data received from the client iny my LINQ to SQL class:

```
//some code
   string commString = "INSERT INTO Token (tk_ID, tk_token, tk_date, tk_IP) VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4)";
   string conString = "placeholder";
   token = GenerateToken(clientLoginData);
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
   {
       using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
       {
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = commString;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", clientLoginData.cl_ID);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", token);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", clientLoginData.LoginTime);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", clientLoginData.cl_IP);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {

            }
    }
//rest of function
```

Is this the correct way to do so? I heard you can do it much easier using

```
SampleDBDataContext dc = new SampleDBDataContext();
```

and then using this variable dc. I never used it however, is it true? And can someone give me example of inserting one value into the table using this?

Comment: That is not Linq to SQL. This is : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is a simple c# code to insert value and not Linq2Sql for Linq2Sql you should have

```
 using (YourDbContext dc=new YourDbContext ()){

         Token item = new Token();
         item.tk_date = clientLoginData.LoginTime;
         item.tk_IP = clientLoginData.cl_IP;
         item.tk_ID = clientLoginData.cl_ID;
         item.tk_token = token;

            dc.Tokens.InsertOnSubmit
            dc.SubmitChanges();
   }
```

[Example 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26657/Simple-LINQ-to-SQL-in-C)

[Example 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399398(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I cannot do `Token.InsertOnSubmit` however I can do `dc.Tokens.InsertOnSubmit` is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
 DataContext dc = new   Using(DataContext(Connections.GetDynamicConnectionfromConfig()))
 {

          Sampleclass obj = new Sampleclass();
          //Here assign properties to obj
          dc.tableName.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
          dc.SubmitChanges();

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

your code should look like this

```
using (SampleDBDataContext dc = new SampleDBDataContext())
{
    Token item = new Token();
    item.tk_ID = clientLoginData.cl_ID;
    item.tk_token = token;
    item.tk_date = clientLoginData.LoginTime;
    item.tk_IP = clientLoginData.cl_IP;
    dc.Tokens.InsertOnSubmit(item);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```